# Dynamic sql - Can't figure out why my code is not echo-ing

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, dynamic

I was wondering if I can get some help and show me what I did wrong here since my code will not echo out. The result does not echo out and it is just a blank page. I am just really frustrated right now and my professor is no help at all and would not tell me what I did wrong. I basically created a search box where I can enter an NBA team name in and it will show the teams record by pulling it from the MS Access database.

I also put in a print command to see what I did wrong and this is what I get if I enter in a western conference team name like the spurs in the search box: **SELECT teamRECORDS FROM nbateam WHERE teamNBA='spurs'**

If anyone can help me out and show me the light, I greatly appreciate it!

```
table: nbateam
Fields: ID, teamNBA, teamRECORDS

**<--nba.html-->**

<form action="nbadetails.php" method="post">

<h2>Current Western Conference NBA Team Records</h2>

<h4>Enter the NBA team name:</h4>
<input type="text" name="teamName">
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Go!">
</form>

**<--nbadetails.php-->**

<?php
$teamname=filter_input (INPUT_POST, "teamName");

$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO"); 
$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data      Source=e:\\server\\kl7\\Database\\nbateam.mdb";

$conn->Open($connString);

$selectCommand="SELECT teamRECORDS FROM nbateam WHERE teamNBA='".$teamname."'";

print $selectCommand;

$rs=$conn->Execute($selectCommand);

if (!$rs->EOF)
{
$teamNBA=$rs->Fields("teamNBA");
echo "Results: $teamNBA";
}
else 
{
echo "You did not enter a western conference NBA team name.";

$rs->Close;
}
?>
```

Comment: The only way I could help you was to add the php tag.

Comment: I am not familiar with connecting to `ms-access`, but you are selecting column `teamRECORDS` (`$selectCommand="SELECT teamRECORDS...`), but calling column `teamNBA` (`$teamNBA=$rs->Fields("teamNBA");`). Shouldn't it be `$teamNBA=$rs->Fields("teamRECORDS");`?

Comment: @Sean - Ah..I am so dumb! It was right there in front of my eyes. I called the wrong Field! I swear I had teamRECORDS at one point but just wasn't sure why it didn't show up, so I changed it through frustration. Might of been my server but thank you so much! I will remember this.

Answer (score 0):

You are not selecting `teamNBA` in your select query.

```
$selectCommand="SELECT teamRECORDS, teamNBA FROM nbateam WHERE teamNBA='$teamname'";
```

You might need to pass in userid and password in connection string try if above not working.

```
$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=e:\\server\\kl7\\Database\\nbateam.mdb"; User    ID=userid;Password=password;
```